# Maxima: how to plot a 2D and 3D vector?

Tags: vector, 3d, 2d, maxima, wxmathplot

What is the simplest way to plot and 2D and 3D vectors using wxMaxima?

I have searched around, but all the solutions seem too complicated just for a single plot of simple vector, is that possible?

I would like to see 3 vectors at the same time in a 3D space in order to visualize a shape, but all options I have seen around seem to make this simple task not so trivial.

Answer (score 3):

[Does it help?](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/de/maxima_42.html#IDX2088)

```
load("draw");

draw3d(vector([0, 0, 0], [100, 0, 0]),
  vector([0, 0, 0], [0, 100, 0]),
  vector([0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 100]));
```